# OpenMp For-Loop Parallelization

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, openmp, parallel.for

I try to parallelize the following piece of code with OpenMP.

```
#pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)
{
    for (int mNdx = 0; mNdx < M; ++mNdx)
    {
        for (int nNdx = mNdx; nNdx < N; ++nNdx)
        {
            for (int elemNdx = mNdx; elemNdx <= nNdx; ++elemNdx)
            {
                result[mNdx * N + nNdx] += matrixOne[mNdx * N + elemNdx] * matrixTwo[elemNdx * N + nNdx];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But the SpeedUp is always about 1.0 (+- 0.05). I tried every possible scheduling (auto, dynamic, static and guided ), different chunk sizes, without collapse and with collapse(2).
The runtime doesn't change at all ...

Can anyone explain me why or where my fault is ? 
Could it be due to automated for-loop compiler parallelization ?

Thanks in advance for any advice/tip !

Update:

As required an verifiable example.

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <iostream>

void initMatrix(float* mat, const int M, const int N);
void initResMatrix(float* mat, const int M, const int N);

double matMulUpperTriangular_C(float* matrixOne, float* matrixTwo, float* result, const int M, const int N);
double matMulUpperTriangular_Omp(float* matrixOne, float* matrixTwo, float* result, const int M, const int N);

int main()
{
    const int M = 2048, N = 2048;
    float* matOne = (float*)malloc(M * N * sizeof(float));
    float* matTwo = (float*)malloc(M * N * sizeof(float));
    float* res = (float*)malloc(M * N * sizeof(float));

    initMatrix(matOne, M, N);
    initMatrix(matTwo, M, N);
    initResMatrix(res, M, N);

    double timeConsumption[2] = { 0.0, 0.0 };

    timeConsumption[0] = matMulUpperTriangular_C(matOne, matTwo, res, M, N);
    timeConsumption[1] = matMulUpperTriangular_Omp(matOne, matTwo, res, M, N);

    std::cout << "Runtime C:\t\t" << timeConsumption[0] << "s" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Runtime Omp:\t\t" << timeConsumption[1] << "s";
    std::cout << " | SpeedUp: " << timeConsumption[0] / timeConsumption[1] << std::endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void initMatrix(float* mat, const int M, const int N)
{
    for (int mNdx = 0; mNdx < M; ++mNdx)
    {
        for (int nNdx = 0; nNdx < mNdx; ++nNdx)
        {
            mat[mNdx * N + nNdx] = 0;
        }
        for (int nNdx = mNdx; nNdx < N; ++nNdx)
        {
            mat[mNdx * N + nNdx] = ((mNdx + nNdx) % 5 + 1) * 0.1f;
        }
    }
}

void initResMatrix(float* mat, const int M, const int N)
{
    for (int mNdx = 0; mNdx < M; ++mNdx)
    {
        for (int nNdx = 0; nNdx < N; ++nNdx)
        {
            mat[mNdx * N + nNdx] = 0.0f;
        }
    }
}

double matMulUpperTriangular_C(float* matrixOne, float* matrixTwo, float* result, const int M, const int N)
{
    double startTime = omp_get_wtime();

    for (int mNdx = 0; mNdx < M; ++mNdx)
    {
        for (int nNdx = mNdx; nNdx < N; ++nNdx)
        {
            for (int elemNdx = mNdx; elemNdx <= nNdx; ++elemNdx)
            {
                result[mNdx * N + nNdx] += matrixOne[mNdx * N + elemNdx] * matrixTwo[elemNdx * N + nNdx];
            }
        }
    }

    double endTime = omp_get_wtime();

    return endTime - startTime;
}

double matMulUpperTriangular_Omp(float* matrixOne, float* matrixTwo, float* result, const int M, const int N)
{
    double startTime = omp_get_wtime();

    #pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)
    {
        for (int mNdx = 0; mNdx < M; ++mNdx)
        {
            for (int nNdx = mNdx; nNdx < N; ++nNdx)
            {
                for (int elemNdx = mNdx; elemNdx <= nNdx; ++elemNdx)
                {
                    result[mNdx * N + nNdx] += matrixOne[mNdx * N + elemNdx] * matrixTwo[elemNdx * N + nNdx];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    double endTime = omp_get_wtime();

    return endTime - startTime;
}
```

Solved:

Stupid mistake ...
had set the /MP-Flag (Build with Multiple Processes) instead of /openmp.
Now the SpeedUp is about 2.0 :)

Sorry and thank you all for your help !

Comment: You have a reduction and loops not in canonical form, I would have expected a message from the compiler.

Comment: How do you time it?

Comment: I time it with omp_get_wtime()  ... one call direct before this loop and one directly after.

Comment: Just to make sure: Did you enable openmp support in the compiler options and did you include the omp.h header to your file? Could you provide a [minimal, correct and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? This helps people to better understand your problem.

Comment: OpenMp flag is set (compiled with visual studio 2015) and omp.h is also included. Will add an verifiable  example.

Comment: @Paul R. You were right ... had set the false flag, thank you ! Better look twice -.-

Comment: I think there is another problem with this code. I never used collapse myself before, but If I understand it right, there is a race condition in the inner loop.  `result[mNdx * N + nNdx] +=` can be executed by different threads having different `elemNdx` but identical `mNdx` and `nNdx`. Maybe collapse(2) would be a better choice.

Comment: Had to remove the collapse, the vs-compiler supports only OpenMP 2.0. Collapse is a OpenMP 3.0 feature. But your argument is also correct, this should cause an race condition. So collapse(2) should be the correct option, if you can use collapse at all.

Comment: Actually, you cannot use `collapse` at all here since the 2nd level loop isn't in the [canonical form](http://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/openmp-4.5.pdf#section.2.6), as it uses the 1st level index as start for iteration. The most important art of the standard that forbids collapsing your construct is: "**The _b_, _lb_ and _incr_ expressions may not reference _var_ of any of the associated loops.**"